# Problemas com Grid Layout gerado dinâmicamente

Tags: php, layout, bootstrap, grid

Bom dia, pessoal!

Sou iniciante na área de front-end e é uma das primeiras vezes que estou utilizando o Boostrap. Desta vez, preciso entregar um trabalho para a escola e para isso desenvolvi uma espécia de "feed" dividido em duas colunas, porém não consigo fazer com que as colunas quebrem automaticamente.

Os itens estão dispostos dentro de uma `ol`, e cada `li` está dentro de um for que pega as informações do banco de dados. Segue o trecho do código e a imagem de como é apresentado:

```
<div id="feed">
   <ol id="feed-lista">
      <?php for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($posts); $i++){ ?>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <li class="feed-container panel">
                <div class="feed-item">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        [...itens do menu lateral...]
                    </div>
                     <img src="<?= $posts[$i]['foto_perfil'] ?>" class="feed-foto" alt="Foto de perfil de <?= $posts[$i]['nome'].' '.$posts[$i]['sobrenome']?>" />

                    <div class="feed-dados">
                    <a href="profile.php?username=<?= $posts[$i]['username'] ?>" >
                    <span class="feed-nome"><?= $posts[$i]['nome'].' '.$posts[$i]['sobrenome'] ?></span></a>
                    <span class="feed-username"> &bull; <a class="feed-username" href="profile.php?username=<?= $posts[$i]['username'] ?> ">@<?= $posts[$i]['username'] ?></a></span>

                        <div class="feed-data">
                        [... código para tratamento da data ...]
                        </div>

                </div>


                <div class="feed-conteudo">
                    <div class="feed-texto">
                        <?= $posts[$i]['status']?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="feed-localizacao">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> em <?= $posts[$i]['local']." - ". $posts[$i]['cidade'].", ".$posts[$i]['pais']  ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</ol>
</div>
```

O código acima retorna isso:
[image: Exibição]

No CSS em si, foram utilizadas apenas formatações para os itens de dentro de cada `li`, mas nada referente ao posicionamento. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Um exemplo mais conhecido de como eu gostaria que ficasse (sendo gerado dinamicamente) é o feed do Google Plus:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muitíssimo obrigado à todos!

Answer (score 0):

Cara, tem um plugin que faz isso, com bootstrap será meio complicado você conseguir.

De um estudada, é bem prático.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

```js
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options...
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 200
});
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

Seria mais ou menos assim, as grid item seriam suas li. 
Este plugin faz com que de acordo com a resolução da sua tela ele se adapte e deixe de forma responsiva automaticamente.

Comment: Não existe alguma forma de fazer com o Bootstrap mesmo? Independente de ser complicado ou não, mas é pelo fato de que utilizar plug-ins acaba descontando nas notas recebidas.

Comment: Bem feito igual esse, não, creio que você não va receber nota negativa pelo fato de usar esse plugin, é algo mais complexo e fica um layout top.
Com bootstrap tu pode deixar todos do mesmo tamanho, da um height e deixa todos do mesmo tamanho hahaah. Pode usar um display table para centralizar também caso necessário.

Comment: Utilizando dessa forma, como eu faço pra que o tamanho das colunas seja responsivo com o tamanho da página?

Comment: Pode dar height nas divs e colocar o conteúdo dentro, depois qualquer coisa limita com php as letras ou palavras. Responsividade você pode dividar com os COLs do bootstrap, onde você divide por exemplo class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"
Isso vai fazer com que pra cima de 1200 ficará 4 partes, pra cima de 991 até 1200 ficará com 3 partes, de 768 até 1024 em 2 partes e pra baixo de 768 12 partes.

Comment: Isso não vai conflitar com o columnWidth do Masonry?

Comment: Se você vai usar masonry aí é diferente, tenta ler a documentação e procura algo, mas tem bastante na internet. Somente procurar que vai achar, e pensar um pouco também, é bem simples, pode ser que quebre a cabeça no começo, mas depois vai ver como é fácil.